# Как создать модуль Angular 2 на es6 без typeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2

Изучаю Angular 2. Решил для изучения попробовать написать на ES6 вместо TS.
Безрезультатно пытаюсь создать модуль. Проблема уже на этапе импортирования NgModule. Webpack не ругается, но NgModule = undefined в консоле.

```
'use strict';

import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

import {NgModule} from "angular2/core";
console.log(NgModule); 
// undefined ^

import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

let boot = document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
});
```

С компонентами такой проблемы не возникало. Они создаются, работают и взаимодействуют. И еще дополнительный вопрос - где можно почитать об Angular на es6? 99% примеров в интернете написаны на TS.

Comment: Angular 2 написан на TypeScript .Angular 2: почему на TypeScript? https://habrahabr.ru/company/piter/blog/320064/

Comment: Ангуляровцы забили на js... А вообще, пора уже забить на сам ангуляр.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это почему надо ?

Comment: Я пробовал писать на Angular 2 + TS и мне понравилось. Но чисто для изучения хочу написать на JS.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, потому что писать неудобно, работает так себе, обновляется тоже так себе (до сих пор не знаю, что исправить, чтобы [обновиться с 4.0.0 до 4.0.1](//stackoverflow.com/q/43151731/4928642)). Без славы первого ангуляра он бы вообще не взлетел.

Comment: @aim Для изучения вы выбрали неверный способ.Лучше углубить знания в js А вокруг него так много всего крутится что времени н хватит их изучить.А время не вернуть :)

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan Время, конечно самый ценный ресурс:) Но я уже несколько лет углубляю знания в js. И много работал с первым ангуляром. Сейчас хочу изучить второй.

Comment: @aim777 Так не тратьте время зря.если сказано что angular написан на TS то скорее всего у вас ничего не получится.Eсли у вас есть столько времени то лучше напишите свой вариант с нуля  :),вместо траты времени в пустоту.А так хоть TS изучите .

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan angular 2 поддерживает TS, ES6 и Dart. И моя воля - я бы написал по приложению на каждом из вариантов

Comment: @aim777 Остается пожелать вам всего лишь удачи.:)

Answer (score 0):

Написать на TS и откомпилировать код в es6. Результат будет ответом на ваш вопрос)

Comment: Так себе ответ...